# jQuery event delegation & PJAX events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pushstate, pjax

I have a Rails 3.2 app with a menu toggle div for displaying a horizontal nav menu. After the back or forward button is clicked, a click of the div no longer toggles the menu. I have tried using event delegation and pjax events to fix this issue, but nothing seems to work.

When event delegation and/or pjax events aren't used the toggle works correctly on full refresh and pjax requests, but breaks on back/forward button. When I add delegation or pjax events in different combos, the problems occur. Here are several different scripts I've tried. I'm getting very weird results, working sometimes and not others... I'm concerned I may not be combining them correctly. These are all wrapped in script tags on the particular view, vs in application.js. Thanks for your help!

**1. No event delegation, works besides back/forward**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');
  }); 
});
```

**2. With event delegation, works SOMETIMES, never for back/forward**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.menu-toggle', function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');  
  });
});
```

**3. With pjax:end event inside document ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');    
  }); 


  $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
      $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });
  });
});
```

**4. With pjax:end outside document ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.menu-toggle', function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');  
  });
});

$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
      $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the event delegated script to application.js inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $('body').on('click', '.menu-toggle', function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });

});
```